# PHP: Load webpage, which loads some content with dynamically ajax

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am currently using CURL to load certain webpages and then parse them. It was working fine, but some of them started to load parts of them dynamically with ajax. As a result, those parts are missing from the content, returned by curl_exec() method.

Is this possible to load full content, including dynamic/ajax content in php? Maybe there are some libraries, which can help me to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you know what ajax calls the page is making (you can monitor this with firebug or a similar tool in the browser) then you can do an additional curl request that replicates the ajax request.

Comment: No, they can be different. Is there any generic solution?

Comment: If they are different you have to parse it by a javascript engine and you must supply a DOM interface to that html document. This is the same task as a standard browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to execute JavaScripts in PHP.

If you only access a few websites, consider hardcoding/extracting the urls of the ajax calls and sending additional requests to those urls manually.